# Extracting mean, sd and confidence interval from a command

Tags: stata

I am using Stata to conduct survey analysis and I am running the command:

```
quietly svy: mean consumption
```

I need to extract the results and put them in a matrix.

How do I extract the mean, sd and confidence intervals?

I believe for the mean we can run:

```
matrix[1,2] = e(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
webuse nhanes2f
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)
quietly svy: mean zinc

return list

scalars:
              r(level) =  95

macros:
           r(mcmethod) : "noadjust"

matrices:
              r(table) :  9 x 1

matrix list r(table)

r(table)[9,1]
             zinc
     b  87.182067
    se  .49448269
     t  176.30965
pvalue  4.244e-48
    ll  86.173563
    ul  88.190571
    df         31
  crit  2.0395134
 eform          0
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a question - does that mean it will be e(se), e(ll) and e(ul) for individual extraction of results?

Comment: I ask this because I do not want other values. Apparently, e(se), e(ll) and e(ul) doesn't work.

Comment: I have already fully answered your question. You need to study matrices in Stata instead of asking me really basic questions.